# binary:logistic like parameter in LightGBM

Tags: lightgbm

I want my predictions in probabilities between 0 and 1. I already did that in xgboost but I wanna try out Lightgbm too but its outputting solid predictions(that is in integer only). I could do that in XGBoost by setting 'objective' parameter to binary:logistic but in Lightgbm there doesn't seem to be any parameter like that, It only has binary and it is giving output in 0 or 1.

Comment: in both XGBoost and LightGBM there is a difference between predicted probabilities and labels, labels being integers, which are evaluated as `(probability > threashold).astype(int)`

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi ok, so I want to estimate probability between 0 and 1, so do I need to change source code for that?

Comment: You'd need to provide an example; for me, setting objective to 'binary' gives outputs as probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

To get the class probability between 0 and 1 in lightgbm, you have to use a default value of a parameter "objective" is a regression.

```
'objective' = 'binary' ( return class label 0 or 1)
'objective' = 'regression' ( return class probability between 0 and 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting objective: “multiclass” with num_class: 2 as parameters. The results might not be the same with direct binary classification model yet I can ensure you that there will be no performance loss.

Bonus: As loss metric, you can use “multi_error” or “multi_logloss” or interestingly a combination of both like: 
metric: “multi_error”, “multi_logloss”

Answer (score -1):

You can use `predict(raw_score=True)`

If you are using the `sklearn API` - You can use objective "binary", just use `predict_proba()` instead of `predict()`